# malloc failed in C HTTP server: terminate or internal server error?

Tags: c, http, malloc, internal-server-error

I have a web server written C, just for learning purposes. I recognize a pattern in C programming that when there is a failed `malloc`, developers will terminate the process (`perror` and `exit`). This is what I've been doing.

However, HTTP has the 500 status code, whose message is "Internal Server Error". Instead of terminating the whole server, it simply returns a response to the clients. But if it just returns the error response, the next `malloc` will be likely yield the same error response.

So I wonder:

1. How do you handle failed functions such as `mmap` and `malloc`?
2. What failed C functions should I return an internal server error instead of terminating the server?

Assume the error only happens during reading requests and sending responses.

Comment: What if the first malloc is for 2TB of memory, and the second is for 2KB? Why would the second fail?

Comment: Your allocation handling strategy is often dictated by the situation you're handling as well. In the case of a request/response model like HTTP then maybe that request can't be processed, but others can, so I'd say 500 and move on. If this was a desktop application where a single failed allocation is likely a sign of an impending failure, then maybe a hard exit is the better plan.

Comment: "[By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation
       strategy.  This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there
       is no guarantee that the memory really is available.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)"

Answer (score 1):

In general, dealing with (and recovering from) malloc failure is going to be heavily application dependent.  In general, you'll need to call `free` on some things if you want to have later malloc calls not also fail.

In the context of a web server, you might have caches of data (stuff that was read from files and is kept in order to make future requests faster).  You might clear or flush these caches (freeing all data or just data that hasn't been used recently) which could free up enough space that later malloc calls won't fail.

Comment: would it be a good idea to load error files like 500 beforehand and store them somewhere? The reason why I asked this questions was because [RFC 7231#6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) says that "the
   server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
   error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent". If my malloc fails, reading these static files as error representation is undoable.

Comment: It's often a good approach to "preallocate" critical stuff you may need to handle a malloc failure, so that you can get to the point of actually dealing with it by freeing up non-critical things.  That would include things like those message replies you may want to send.